# how to read the properties of a react component passed to a regular function?

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props, higher-order-functions, react-hoc

I have a HOC:

```
 function withNavigationWatcher(Component: React.ComponentType<RouteComponentProps<any>> | React.ComponentType<any>) {
  console.log('withNavigationWatcher Component', Component.props)
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
  return function (props: any) {
    const { setNavigationData } = useNavigation();
    useEffect(() => {
      setNavigationData({ currentPath: props.match.path });
      // eslint-disable-next-line react/destructuring-assignment
    }, [props.match.path, setNavigationData]);

    return React.createElement(Component, props);
  };
}
```

it is called like a normal function, which is passed the component:

```
component: withNavigationWatcher(route.component),
```

So I can only access default props in **withNavigationWatcher** ?
but is it possible to access the props property of component - even if they are not set, is there a reference to this property?

[image]

and the second question: taken in the second function?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass both props, default props and component level props to returned component. Try to create new object with both props and sent it to component.

```
ley newProps = {...props, ...Component.props}
```

...
return React.createElement(Component, newProps);

Please refer to this article

https://medium.com/@jrwebdev/react-higher-order-component-patterns-in-typescript-42278f7590fb
I think instead on any you need to attach props interface

```
interface WithLoadingProps {
  loading: boolean;
}

const withLoading = <P extends object>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) =>
  class WithLoading extends React.Component<P & WithLoadingProps> {
    render() {
      const { loading, ...props } = this.props;
      return loading ? <LoadingSpinner /> : <Component {...props as P} />;
    }
  };
```

Comment: you can see in the screenshot that the Сomponent does not have the props property, 
this is the question whether it is possible to get this data in any way, even if there is an object with indefined properties